# How do I switch back to Evolution and ensure that it is integrated with the desktop?

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, messaging-menu

I would like to use Evolution as the default mail client. Thus, I'd like to have Evolution integrated with the desktop instead of Thunderbird (especially concerning the mail symbol on the desktop bar). Has anyone experience 'reverting' to Evolution?

I did change the *Mail* client setting in the *Default Applications* section in System Info dialog from '*Thunderbird*' to '*Evolution*'. This has the effect that the mail application started from Unity Launcher is indeed Evolution, yet, this setting does not replace Thunderbird with Evolution in the desktop bar. And, it does not enable desktop notifications for Evolution, as a consequence.

Comment: Are you using 11.10?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 11.10. Just realized I used the wrong tag, corrected that by now, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install evolution-indicator, but DO NOT uninstall thunderbird, otherwise the indicator will not show.

`sudo apt-get install evolution-indicator`

Answer (score 2):

Go to System settings, and click on System information and go the Predefined aplications and change Thunderbird to Evolution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as expected. See my edit of the original post.

Comment: It's called "details" now.

Answer (score 0):

[Missing evolution mail and chat icons from panel in oneric ocelot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87352/missing-evolution-mail-and-chat-icons-from-panel-in-oneric-ocelot)

I was trying to do the same thing, and I found this thread that worked!