# Missing evolution mail and chat icons from panel in oneric ocelot

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel, evolution, empathy

I had Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my machine. Upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 and installed weather-indicator. After this, my evolution mail and chat(empathy) icons that were placed in the panel (at right-up screen corner) disappeared. I want to put them back, so that I'll be notified by evolution mail or chatting programs.

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using gnome-classic or the unity interface?

Comment: @fossfreedom I'm using the unity interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its worth checking that you have the evolution and empathy indicators installed:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall evolution-indicator indicator-messages
```

Logout and login for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I upgraded my wife's laptop to 11.10 with KDE. I tried the suggestion above and others I had found with no luck. I reinstalled evolution and Oxygen with no luck. .xsession-errors had a series of lines indicating missing icons when I started evolution (Unfortunately I lost the output from .xsession-errors and I can't provide them here.)

I have a similar configuration on my laptop, and evolution was working fine on it, so I did a stare and compare in Synaptic and corrected a couple of minor difference. Still no joy.

Finally I decided to copy the /usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16, 22x22, 24x24, etc. directories from my laptop to hers. This seems to have done the trick. I made sure to rename the old files just in case I need to revert back.

This is not a correct answer to this problem; there is probably a package missing that I have overlooked somehow. But it seems to work and it saved me from another day of tearing my hair out.