# How can I get the mail tray menu to switch from Thunderbird back to Evolution?

Tags: unity, 16.04, email, evolution, system-tray

On Ubuntu 16 I switched back to Evolution as my default email client. It's set correctly in the system settings. But when I click the envelope (mail) icon in the top panel (tray), the only option is to launch Thunderbird.
How can I get the mail tray menu to switch from Thunderbird back to Evolution?

This did not work :

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall evolution-indicator indicator-messages` (logged in and out many times)
- I have no "missing icon" error in .xsession-errors
- I heard that uninstalling Thunderbird is not recommended

My main goal was to get email notifications, so I have installed many tasks, in the system-monitor I see : notify-osd, mail-notification, and indicator-messages-service

This fix didn't work [How do I switch back to Evolution and ensure that it is integrated with the desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68681/how-do-i-switch-back-to-evolution-and-ensure-that-it-is-integrated-with-the-desk)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40004/changing-email-application-in-preferred-applications-to-gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I uninstalled Thunderbird, I just lost the mail icon in the tray, then reinstalled Thunderbird. I got the mail icon back, but nothing was fixed.

Then I launched Evolution, and the tray envelope icon menu did what I wanted : switch back to Evolution. Seems to be fixed. I wanted this, though I wasn't launching Evolution a lot.